# ListView with subitems avoid 2 times same information

Tags: android, listview, simplecursoradapter

I have a ListView populated with my database using a SimpleCursorAdapter. 
I have 2 lines in my ListView , 1 for the date (one column of my table) and the other for 2 columns of my db as well.

The 1st column is the date, 2nd is the lesson and the 3rd is the theme of the lesson.

The problem is : If I have more than one lesson the same day, it will show like this in my app :

15.05.17

English Reading

15.05.17

English Listening

But, I would like that, if I have more than one lesson the same day, I just want to display the first line once (at the top), like this:

15.05.17

English Reading

English Listening

How can I do that ?

Here's my list_row_page_itude.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:padding="16dp">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_date"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Date"/>

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="11dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_branche_cours"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="English"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_trait"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text=" - " />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_designation"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Reading"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

How I implement it in my code :

```
lvJalons = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.ListJalons);
    Cursor cursor = dbhelper.getAllJalons();
    String[] from = { "date_point", "designation_jalon","description_jalon" };
    int[] to = {R.id.text_date,R.id.text_branche_cours, R.id.text_designation };
    adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.list_row_page_itude, cursor, from, to, 0);
    lvJalons.setAdapter(adapter);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

And the method on my db that I use (getAllJalons()):

```
` public Cursor getAllJalons()
{
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    Date date = c.getTime();
    String currentDate = df.format(date);

    String query = ("select ID as _id,date_jalon,date_point,devoir,evaluation,importance,designation_jalon, description_jalon,cours_fk from "+TABLE_JALONS+" where date(date_jalon) >='"+currentDate+"'");
    Open();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query,null);
    return cursor;
}`
```

Thank you guys.

Answer (score 0):

CursorAdapters directly do not support sectioning. You could have a look at this project which extends that functionality to CursorAdapters - https://github.com/twotoasters/SectionCursorAdapter

Comment: I had a look in your link.. but don't you have an example for my problem please ?